# .NET Core 3.0 IHostedService access web server URL - scheme, host, port etc

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, kestrel-http-server

The issue that I have is simple. I want to access the server URL in my `IHostedService`.

I cannot find a way to do it. There isn't any request there so I cannot use the `IHttpContextAccessor`.

`IServer` features property doesn't have any addresses and I am out of options.

I do not want to hard code the URL of the server in the configuration.

The version of .NET core that I am running is 3.0.

Comment: I mean, you can inject `IHttpContextAccessor` into your class... If you could give more context about where/when you need the information, I would think we could help you better.

Comment: I need it in a IHostedService, which is executed right after the start of the application. IHttpContextAccessor requires a Request and can be used in the controller. But in IHostedService I do not have a request

Comment: Long story short, you can't. See [How do I get the website URL or access the HttpContext from a IHostedService in ASP.NET Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57004484/215552)

Comment: Isn't there another way ? A way not using HttpContext ?

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293229/get-base-url-from-service-layer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get the address/url from your server before you completely start the server.

If you need your localhost address, look it up (programmatically or otherwise) from `./Properties/launchSettings.json`.

If you need the address in a live environment, you have to wait for the server to load.

Answer (score 4):

You can register your hosted service with the dependency injection framework in `Startup.cs`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, MyHostedService>();
}
```

Then, you can inject an `IServer` into your hosted service and get the addresses using `IServerAddressesFeature`:

```
public class MyHostedService : IHostedService
{
    private readonly IServer _server;

    public MyHostedService(IServer server)
    {
       _server = server;
    }

    public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
       var features = _server.Features;
       var addresses = features.Get<IServerAddressesFeature>();
       var address = addresses.Addresses.FirstOrDefault(); // = http://localhost:5000
    }
}
```

Comment: No addresses in IServerAddressesFeature for Asp.Net Core 3.1 using default web server builder locally running IIS Express, at least, even with a lauchSettings.json and an IIS Express profile

Comment: Addresses are empty in ASP.NET Core 6 when doing this.

Answer (score 1):

For Asp.Net Core 3.1, you cannot get addresses from `IServerAddressesFeature` in `IHostedService` because `IHostedService`s are launched before `Server`. See this [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/22350#issuecomment-635972791).

> What has changed is the ordering of IHostedService's being called. This was moved up in 3.0, but still runs after Configure.

To get addresses in your `IHostedService`s you can make them run After `Startup`. I found one of the approaches is to register your service in `Program.cs`, see it in detail [here](https://andrewlock.net/controlling-ihostedservice-execution-order-in-aspnetcore-3/).

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
        => CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => // The GenericWebHostSevice is registered here
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            })
            // Register your HostedService AFTER ConfigureWebHostDefaults
            .ConfigureServices(
                services => services.AddHostedService<ProgramHostedService>());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In .NET 6, I couldn't find a way to affect the order in which the hosted services are started, so I had to find another way.
Luckily, there's `IHostApplicationLifetime` which lets you hook into the `ApplicationStarted` lifecycle event.
Oddly, `ApplicationStarted` is a `CancellationToken`, and not a C# event.
You can use the `Register` method on the cancellation token to run code when the web application has started.
At this point, the URLs will be populated on the `IServer` object.

Here's an example with `IHostedService`:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.Features;

public class MyHostedService : IHostedService
{
    private readonly IServer _server;
    private readonly IHostApplicationLifetime _hostApplicationLifetime;

    public MyHostedService(IServer server, IHostApplicationLifetime hostApplicationLifetime)
    {
        _server = server;
        _hostApplicationLifetime = hostApplicationLifetime;
    }

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Address before application has started: {GetAddress()}");

        _hostApplicationLifetime.ApplicationStarted.Register(
                () => Console.WriteLine($"Address after application has started: {GetAddress()}"));
        
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private string GetAddress()
    {
        var features = _server.Features;
        var addresses = features.Get<IServerAddressesFeature>();
        var address = addresses.Addresses.FirstOrDefault();
        return address;
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) => Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

When you run the application, the output will look like this:

```
Address before application has started:
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: https://localhost:7012
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5012
Address after application has started: https://localhost:7012
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Development
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: C:\Users\niels\RiderProjects\UrlsInHostedService\UrlsInHostedService\
```

As you can see by the output, there's no address on `IServer` when the hosted service is started, but then the server starts, and the `ApplicationStarted` cancellation token is cancelled, which triggers the callback and now there are URLs on `IServer`.

In my case, I actually needed it for `BackgroundService` in which case it works better IMO, because you can create your own task and `await` it. Here's an example:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.Features;

public class MyBackgroundService : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly IServer _server;
    private readonly IHostApplicationLifetime _hostApplicationLifetime;

    public MyBackgroundService(IServer server, IHostApplicationLifetime hostApplicationLifetime)
    {
        _server = server;
        _hostApplicationLifetime = hostApplicationLifetime;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Address before application has started: {GetAddress()}");

        await WaitForApplicationStarted();
        
        Console.WriteLine($"Address after application has started: {GetAddress()}");
    }

    private string GetAddress()
    {
        var features = _server.Features;
        var addresses = features.Get<IServerAddressesFeature>();
        var address = addresses.Addresses.FirstOrDefault();
        return address;
    }    
    
    private Task WaitForApplicationStarted()
    {
        var completionSource = new TaskCompletionSource(TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously);
        _hostApplicationLifetime.ApplicationStarted.Register(() => completionSource.TrySetResult());
        return completionSource.Task;
    }
}
```

The result would be the same as the hosted service, but you do have to use `BackgroundService` and `ExecuteAsync` which may not make sense for your use case.